# Validations on OVF Properties on Vcenter deployment

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter, ovf

I am customizing an OVF template XML by adding OVF properties.  I have a question related to validating the properties.

If a property doesn't succeed the validation test (say, it falls short of a MinLength check), then I see a red warning right below the field (while deploying the OVF in a vCenter). But the user is still able to proceed and click (Submit or next button).

Is there a way to stop the user from proceeding when any validation criteria is not met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of reading came to understand that there are no hooks currently provided to stop the user from proceeding.

Only a warning message gets displayed and the user is solely responsible to go ahead with the install with unmet pre-conditions.